# Rails-- Expressing values of attributes from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object Guess and did

y guess = Guess.find_by_id(5)

and got this

```
id: "5"
firstanswer_chambersapp: f
firstanswer_interview: f
firstanswer_letter: f
firstanswer_drafting: f
firstanswer_barrister: f
firstanswer_solicitor: t
secondanswer_chambersapp: "6"
secondanswer_interview: "2"
secondanswer_letter: "3"
secondanswer_drafting: "5"
secondanswer_barrister: "4"
secondanswer_solicitor: "1"
```

What I want to do is get all the `secondanswers_` and sort them by the integer value (ASC). Is there a way I can do that in ruby/rails?

I'm expecting it to involve

```
guess.each do |e|

 end
```

but I'm lost as to the code in the middle :(

Any hints would be helpful. I could also obviously retrieve all results at once

```
y guess = Guess.all
```

If that makes them any easier to sort

I'm also wondering if I set the database up the wrong way to make it practical to retrieve the values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Guess.select(Guess.column_names.select{|field| field =~ /^secondanswer_/}).find(5)
```

That will return only the secondanswer_* fields for the record.

```
Guess.select(Guess.column_names.select{|field| field =~ /^secondanswer_/}).sort{|a,b| a.secondanswer_champbersapp <=> b.secondanswer_chambersapp}
```

Would return all Guess records sorted by secondanswer_chambersapp.

Comment: thank you . I can read it, but I never would have been able to figure that out, and I'm having trouble implementing it. <br/>  I got an unexpected token error in the console when I did:  Guess.select(Guess.column_names.select{|field| field =~ /^secondanswer_/}).sort{|a,b| a.secondanswer_champbersapp <=> b.secondanswer_chambersapp} and got an unexpected token "("